# python sqlite3 update not updating

Tags: python, sqlite

Question: Why is this sqlite3 statement not updating the record?

---

Info:

```
cur.execute('UPDATE workunits SET Completed=1 AND Returns=(?) WHERE PID=(?) AND Args=(?)',(pickle.dumps(Ret),PID,Args))
```

I'm using python and sqlite3. this statement does not throw an error, it just seems like it is out right ignored. for testing reasons I included below it:

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM workunits WHERE PID=(?) AND Args=(?)',(PID,Args))
```

Which returns a record just fine. but the record doesn't up date with the new value of the pickled ret. it remains u''. I can't figure out why. my where statement seems to work. my syntax seems to be correct because there is no error being thrown. I'm clueless as to why exactly it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

don't use 'AND', use a ','.

```
cur.execute('UPDATE workunits SET Completed=1, Returns=? WHERE PID=? AND Args=?',
    (pickle.dumps(Ret), PID, Args)
)
```

Comment: You're welcome. For bonus points, try to understand what you statement does and why that isn't an error.

Answer (score 39):

If the problem persists after you fixed your syntax. Please make sure you're using:

```
conn.commit()
```

After cur.execute, UPDATES and INSERTS require COMMIT.

Comment: thanks! spent 1 hour just debuggin my query! phewwww!!!